# CSS3 Fullscreen Slideshow hides too much

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, opacity, css-animations

I am using a small CSS3 solution I found somewhere. It should shuffle (opacity) through the images. However also the img is faded. footer is not touched for what reason ever.

Fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CyJbg/)

Here is the relevant code:

index.html

```
<body>
   <img src="images/logo.png" /> 
    <ul class="cb-slideshow">
            <li><span>Image 01</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 02</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 03</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 04</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 05</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 06</span></li>
    </ul>
    <footer>
    ....`
```

css

```
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.cb-slideshow:after {
    z-index: 1;
    content: '';
    background: transparent url(../images/pattern.png) repeat top left;
}
.cb-slideshow li span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
    .cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { background-image: url(../images/1.jpg) }
    .cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
    background-image: url(../images/2.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
 ....
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? I made one, but as I don't have your images, I can't see what's supposed to happen.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CyJbg/